# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service' error using Python Selenium ChromeDriver with company pac file

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been struggling with this problem for sometime, but now I'm coming back around to it.  I'm attempting to use selenium to scrape data from a URL behind a company proxy using a pac file.
I'm using Chromedriver, which my browser uses the pac file in it's configuration.

I've been trying to use desired_capabilities, but the documentation is horrible or I'm not grasping something.  Originally, I was attempting to webscrape with beautifulsoup, which I had working except the data I need now is in javascript, which can't be read with bs4.

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()

PAC_PROXY = {
    'proxyAutoconfigUrl': 'http://proxy-pac/proxy.pac',
}
proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_autoconfig_url = PAC_PROXY['proxyAutoconfigUrl']

desired_capabilities = {}
proxy.add_to_capabilities(desired_capabilities)
URL = "https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query=ALIMENTARY%20TRACT%20AND%20METABOLISM%7CATC1-4&searchBy=class&sourceIds=a&drugSources=atc1-4%7Catc%2Cepc%7Cdailymed%2Cmeshpa%7Cmesh%2Cdisease%7Cmedrt%2Cchem%7Cdailymed%2Cmoa%7Cdailymed%2Cpe%7Cdailymed%2Cpk%7Cmedrt%2Ctc%7Cfmtsme%2Cva%7Cva%2Cdispos%7Csnomedct%2Cstruct%7Csnomedct%2Cschedule%7Crxnorm"

service = Service('C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(URL)
print(driver.requests[0].headers, driver.requests[0].response)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr.dbsearch')))
print(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1].iloc[:,:-1])
pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1].iloc[:,:-1].to_csv('table.csv',index=False)
```

I'm not sure why I'm receiving an:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

even when I have the path added correctly to my system environment variables as shown below:

[image]

Essentially what I'm attempting to do is scrape the data in the table from `https://mor.nlm.nih.gov/RxClass/search?query=ALIMENTARY%20TRACT%20AND%20METABOLISM%7CATC1-4&searchBy=class&sourceIds=a&drugSources=atc1-4%7Catc%2Cepc%7Cdailymed%2Cmeshpa%7Cmesh%2Cdisease%7Cmedrt%2Cchem%7Cdailymed%2Cmoa%7Cdailymed%2Cpe%7Cdailymed%2Cpk%7Cmedrt%2Ctc%7Cfmtsme%2Cva%7Cva%2Cdispos%7Csnomedct%2Cstruct%7Csnomedct%2Cschedule%7Crxnorm` then store it to a pandas dataframe and pass it to a csv file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are still using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) ***v3.x*** then you shouldn't use the *`Service()`* and in that case the *key* ***executable_path*** is relevant. In that case the lines of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe')
```

---

Else, if you are using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) then you have to use *`Service()`* and in that case the *key* ***executable_path*** is no more relevant. So you need to change the line of code:

```
service = Service(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

as:

```
service = Service('C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Hi Debanjan, thank you for the reply.  I am using Selenium 4.10.  I've updated the line to service = Service('C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe'), but i'm still getting TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'.  The code above has also been updated to show the change.

Comment: Cross check once if you are still on _Selenium 3.x_

Comment: I never had 3.x, only 4.10.  What am I missing?

Comment: @user1470034 We are still at **v4.1.0**, where did you find _v4.10_?

Comment: Missed the . on that reply

Comment: You were correct, even though the python library installed was 4.1.0 it was still reading as Selenium v3.x.  Not, sure how that happened, but using webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Chrome Driver\chromedriver.exe') worked.

Answer (score 5):

I've been having this problem also since I switched from pip Jupyter to Anaconda Jupyter. This worked for me:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Apparently you don't need the service in the Jupyter package.

Answer (score 3):

due to changes in selenium 4.10.0: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

the first argument is no longer `executable_path`, but `options`.
`(ChromeDriverManager().install() )`
returns the path to the install location.) Since selenium manager is now included with `selenium` `4.10.0`, you should no longer use ChromeDriverManager at all.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#.......
driver.quit()
```

However, if you still want to pass in the `executable_path` to an existing driver, you must use the `service` arg now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
service = Service(executable_path="PATH_TO_DRIVER")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
#......
[![enter image description here][1]][1]driver.quit()
```

I got the same error and it worked for me in jupyter and VS code too

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason for seeing: `"TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument"` today is due to changes in `selenium` `4.10.0`, where most args were moved:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e:

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Now, if you want to call `Chrome()` (or another browser), you'll need to pass args into the `options` and `service` args. Here's an example of passing in data in the new format:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.set_capability("cloud:options", {"name": "test_1"})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

(In that example, note that passing in an `executable_path` is optional, as the latest version of selenium now includes a manager that automatically downloads the driver if not found on your PATH.)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve be uninstalling and re-installing selenium

```
pip uninstall selenium
pip install selenium
```

And then using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

Comment: Simply using `pip` to uninstall and reinstall fixed the error.