# Selenium webdriver crashes at start

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to run some selenium program (pythonas.py) which starts with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

firefox_binary_path = '/usr/bin/firefox'

options = Options()
options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
service = Service(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
```

it crashes in webdriver.Firefox() like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonas.py", line 13, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
  File "/home/jk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=self.options)
  File "/home/jk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/jk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/home/jk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/jk/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

I have wsl linux on windows, selenium 4.10 and geckodriver of the version geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz. The paths for firefox and geckodriver are correct.

---

I tried, for example, writing

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

instead. But the output was always the same. I also read posts describing similar issues and tried what the answers suggest, but couldn't solve the problem. What could it be?

Comment: Have you tried running `/usr/bin/firefox` and `/usr/bin/geckodriver` in the temrinal, to see if they display any useful error messages?

Comment: If I write 'which firefox' is prints '/usr/bin/firefox' but if I write '/usr/bin/firefox' it says 'Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified'. '/usr/bin/geckodriver' prints '1688225340276   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444' and it doesn't terminate.

Comment: Then that sounds like the root cause of the exception.  Fix your `DISPLAY` environment variable.  Problem solved!

Comment: Should I get an X server like Xming?

Comment: You need an X display server running on your local machine, and you need to enable X tunnel/forwarding on your connection to the remote machine.

Comment: wsl just have terminal, it have no gui, so it does not provide a full desktop experience,  maybe you should install a gnome.  or you can try using the win10 not the linux

Comment: I got an X server and I can open firefox, use xeyes, xcalc etc, but I still get the same output, just with a different message at the end: "Failed to decode response from marionette". Also when I open firefox through the terminal. get the message: "                                                      [GFX1-]: glxtest: cannot access /sys/bus/pci
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL no display ".

Comment: "options.add_argument("--headless")" fixes the problem. So the problem must be related to the errors  " [GFX1-]: ..."

Answer (score 0):

Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) and the [Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70537951/7429447) class you don't require the [executable_path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553986/7429447) key. So your working code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

firefox_binary_path = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = Options()
options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
s = Service('/usr/bin/geckodriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, options=options)
```

---

While using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v 4.6*** and above, [**Selenium Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) being integrated you no more require to pass the *`**Service**`* object and you can simply:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

firefox_binary_path = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = Options()
options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```